variable in variable cmd bat
I import variables from config.txt to my .bat file.
The following is the content of my config.txt:
param1 = %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs  
param2 = %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Myfolder

This is my .bat file content:
for /f "delims=" %%L in (config.txt) do set %%L  
echo %param1%

This outputs:
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs

But I want it to output:
C:\Users\Alaska\AppData\Local\Programs


If you want another round of variable expansion, use the call command.
If you need the variable to contain %LOCALAPPDATA%, then use it in front of the echo command:
for /f "delims=" %%L in (config.txt) do set %%L
call echo %param1%

If you want the variable to be expanded to its full value, use it in front of the set command:
for /f "delims=" %%L in (config.txt) do call set %%L
echo %param1%


Thanks yes Prefect you'r best <3

The typical solutions are posted already by SomethingDark. It works in most cases.
But these solutions have just some disadvantages.

The usage of call results in one more parsing of the command line which is responsible for expanding %VariableName% by the appropriate value of the reference environment variable. But if the file/folder string contains also a one or more % which are part of a folder/file name and not an environment variable reference, the percent sign (single or last occurrence) or everything between two percent signs is removed from the string resulting in an invalid file/folder string.
The usage of command call results in cmd.exe is searching for a file with name as specified next like set or echo in the current directory and next in all directories of local environment variable PATH with a file extension listed in local environment variable PATHEXT. If a file with that file name and appropriate file extension is really found by chance, the file is executed instead of the cmd internal command set or echo.
An ampersand in file/folder string could be interpreted as unconditional command operator instead of & being part of the file/folder string.

Let us assume the directory C:\Temp\Batch Test contains the file config.txt with the following lines:
param1=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Test1
param2=%TEMP%\Development & Test 100% (!)\Test2
param3="%TEMP%\Development & Test 100% (!) and really 100%\Test3"
param4=..\Data\Test4

This directory contains the batch file Test1.cmd with the lines:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%L in (config.txt) do set %%L
set param
if defined param1 call echo %param1%
if defined param2 call echo %param2%
if defined param3 call echo %param3%
if defined param4 call echo %param4%
endlocal

Running the batch file Test1.cmd with current directory C:\Temp\Batch Test with no file with name echo found in current directory or in the directories of the environment variable PATH with a file extension as listed in the environment variable PATHEXT results in the output:
param1=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Test1
param2=%TEMP%\Development & Test 100% (!)\Test2
param3="%TEMP%\Development & Test 100% (!) and really 100%\Test3"
param4=..\Data\Test4
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Test1
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Development
'Test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Development & Test 100\Test3"
..\Data\Test4

The issues are:

The output of the string value of param2 is wrong and results in interpreting Test after & as additional command to run after echo which outputs just C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Development . The string of param2 is not enclosed in " inside config.txt and the batch file does not recognize that and handle the string accordingly.
% (!) and really 100% in string of param3 is interpreted as reference of an environment variable with name  (!) and really 100. There is no such environment variable, and this part of the folder name is replaced therefore erroneously by an empty string.
The output of param3 is with surrounding " and works for that reason despite & in string value. But it is not good for further batch file processing if the strings assigned to the environment variables param1 to  param4 can be without or with enclosing double quotes.
The string of param4 is still with a relative path to parent directory of the current working directory which could be good but also bad depending on which directory is set as current working directory by the parent process on starting cmd.exe for processing the batch file and depending on batch file is designed to run with current directory or with batch file directory.

The directory C:\Temp\Batch Test also contains a batch file with name Test2.cmd with the following lines:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%L in (config.txt) do call set %%L
set param
endlocal

Running the batch file Test2.cmd with current directory C:\Temp\Batch Test with no file with name set found in current directory or in the directories of the environment variable PATH with a file extension as listed in the environment variable PATHEXT results in the output:
param1=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Test1
param3="C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Development & Test 100\Test3"
param4=..\Data\Test4

The issues are:

The environment variable param2 is not defined at all.
The environment variable param3 has the file/folder string enclosed in " while the other two variables do not have surrounding " which could cause troubles on further processing of the batch file.
% (!) and really 100% is interpreted as reference of an environment variable with name  (!) and really 100. There is no such environment variable, and this part of the folder name is replaced therefore erroneously by an empty string.
The string of param4 is still with a relative path to parent directory of the current working directory which could be good but also bad depending on which directory is set as current working directory by the parent process on starting cmd.exe for processing the batch file and depending on batch file is designed to run with current directory or with batch file directory.

All these disadvantages and issues do not occur with the following batch file Test3.cmd also stored in the directory C:\Temp\Batch Test:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0" || exit /B 1
for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%G in ("%~dp0config.txt") do for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('echo "%%~H"') do set "%%G=%%~fI"
set param
popd
endlocal

This batch file is executed with "C:\Temp\Batch Test\Test3.cmd" with current directory being C:\Users\username as typical on opening a command prompt window. The output is:
param1=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Test1
param2=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Development & Test 100% (!)\Test2
param3=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Development & Test 100% (!) and really 100%\Test3
param4=C:\Temp\Data\Test4

The third command line can be removed if the batch file should use the current working directory as defined outside of the batch file. This line makes sure that the current working directory during the execution of the batch file is the directory containing the batch file with is important for param4.
The advantages are as follows:

There is not used anymore the command call to expand environment variable references in file/folder strings in text file config.txt. The Windows Command Processor searches never for a file with name set or echo in the current working directory or any directory listed in environment variable PATH with a file extension listed in environment variable PATHEXT.
The character % in a file/folder string being part of the name of a file/folder is kept even on expanding environment variable references used in same string.
All four environment variables are defined without surrounding " even on config.txt contain the strings without and with double quotes. The file/folder strings assigned to the four environment variables can be now always referenced with using surrounding " as required for file/folder argument strings of unknown consistence.
The string assigned to the environment variable param4 with the relative path is already expanded to fully qualified file/folder name which is useful if there occurs in further processing an error and the file/folder string assigned to param4 is output in the error message. The user gets in this case a clear information which file/folder cause troubles.

It does not matter if the referenced files/folders exist on batch file execution or do not yet exist and must be created next by the batch file.
The disadvantage of the third solution is the slightly larger execution time because of for each line in config.txt is executed in background one more command process with %ComSpec% and the option /c and the command line specified within second FOR command inside ' with the command echo.
However, the fourth command line in third batch file should be used if the batch file is for general usage. I have seen in nearly 30 years really everything in string referenced with %USERNAME% which is part of other predefined environment variables like USERPROFILE, APPDATA or LOCALAPPDATA. A user can define an account name with all characters allowed in a file/folder name. A script should be written for that reason to correct handle every possible file/folder name string.
